# Error on running a node application executable that executes a Powershell script

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, powershell, package

I have a node application that executes a Powershell script ***helloworld.ps1*** . I want to make an executable of this node application. For this purpose I used [Ziet/pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)
and I managed to create the executable for ***Linux, Mac and Windows*** but I am getting an error when I run the executable on any of the platforms.

Following is the code of node application:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn, child;
let mqtt = require('mqtt');
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://13.58.186.254')
client.setMaxListeners(50);
runCheckScript = function () {

  child = spawn("pwsh", ["./helloworld.ps1"]);
  child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    client.on('connect', () => {

    })
    console.log("Powershell Script: " + data);
  });
  child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
  });
  child.on("exit", function () {
    client.publish("codeblock-poc", "Powershell Script finished");
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    client.end();
  });
  child.stdin.end();

}

module.exports = runCheckScript;
```

The above code is being run by the following file ***app.js***:

```
runner = require('./powershell');

runCheckScript()
```

Following is the Powershell script code:

```
echo "Script working"
Get-Date

Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
```

When I run the node app simply by executing the `node app.js` command, I am able to get the desired output as shown in the following snapshot:

[image: Expected execution when ran through the command]

However, when I am running the executable on Windows I am getting the following error:

[image: Error on windows machine]

And On Mac I am getting the following error:
[image: Error On Mac]

I have tried but kind of stuck now. Please guide me that how should I tackle this problem.

Following is the ***package.json*** file:

```
{
  "name": "poweshell-executable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple poc to execute powershell thorugh node",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "assets": "*.ps1"
  },
  "bin": "index.js",
  "author": "Anshuman Upadhyay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.1",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "mqtt": "^2.18.8",
    "node-powershell": "^3.3.1",
    "time": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "nexe/fuse-box": "3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I revisited the [zeit/pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) docs and they have mentioned to add *pkg* tag in ***package.json***(as shown above) and have the following code in ***index.js*** which is the value of **bin** property of the ***package.json***.

```
path = require('path');
console.log(__dirname + '/' + 'helloworld.ps1');
path.join(__dirname + '/' + 'helloworld.ps1')
```

Now I am creating the executable as `pkg package.json` and now previous error has gone but the script is not executing:

[image: Script not executing after certain changes]

Comment: Is PowerShell Core bundled in your app package?

Comment: I have powershell installed on mac, and in windows it is already there. I spawning the powershell script. Do I need to "require" powershellcore?

Comment: error in mac is that it is unable to find the executable file. Make sure the executable file is compressed along with other files while generating executable. Maybe you need to provide an absolute path.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/nexe/nexe as well.

Comment: That is the problem, I have also added above that I tried the ziet/pkg doc suggestions to make my .ps1 script present inside the executable, but the ps1 file is not executing, as I have shown in the snapshot